# How to convert 3 tuple list to a list of tuple using groupby

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

I have a string below

```
test = '''AWS-1 - opened at Jan 23 2010 10:30:08AM 
AWS-2 - opened at Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM 
AWS-2 - closed at Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM 
AWS-1 - closed at Jan 23 2010 9:43:44PM 
AWS-1 - opened at Feb 1 2010 12:40:28AM
AWS-1 - closed at Jan 23 2010 9:43:44PM
'''
```

My Code

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
y = re.findall(r'\b(\w+-\d+)\s+-\s+(\w+[-.\w]+)\s+at\s+(\w+[\s:.\w]+)\n', test)
print (y)
for key, time in groupby(y,lambda z: y[2]):
for thing in y:
    print( (y[1], key))
print (" ")
```

My Out

`(('AWS-2', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM '), ('AWS-2', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM '))
(('AWS-2', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM '), ('AWS-2', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM '))
(('AWS-2', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM '), ('AWS-2', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM '))
(('AWS-2', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM '), ('AWS-2', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM '))
(('AWS-2', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM '), ('AWS-2', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM '))`

Expected out does not coming `AWS-1`, instead everywhere `AWS-2` is coming

```
(('AWS-1', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 10:30:08AM '), ('AWS-1', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 9:43:44PM '))
(('AWS-1', 'opened', 'Feb 1 2010 12:40:28AM'), ('AWS-1', 'closed', 'Feb 23 2010 9:43:44PM'))
(('AWS-2', 'opened', 'Jan 23 2010 11:04:56AM '), ('AWS-2', 'closed', 'Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM '))
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Posted the out,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is unclear, but it appears you wish to make opened-closed pairs based on parameters.

**Given**

```
import re

import dateutil


records = """\
AWS-1 - opened at Jan 23 2010 10:30:08AM
AWS-2 - opened at Jan 23 2010 11:03:56AM
AWS-2 - closed at Jan 23 2010 1:18:32PM 
AWS-1 - closed at Feb 27 2010 9:32:50PM
AWS-1 - opened at Feb 1 2010 12:50:28AM
AWS-1 - closed at Jan 23 2010 9:32:50PM
"""
```

**Code**

```
def splitlines(s: str) -> tuple:
    """Return tuples of parsed lines: id, status, time."""
    res = []

    for line in s.split("\n"):

        if not line:
            continue            
        parsed = tuple(map(str.strip, filter(None, re.split("(\s-\s)|(at)", line))))
        id_, _, status, _, time = parsed 
        data = id_, status, dateutil.parser.parse(time)
        res.append(data)

    return tuple(res)


def pairwise_records(s: str) -> list:
    """Return paired records according to id, status and time."""
    key = lambda x: (x[0], x[2], x[1])

    sorted_recs = ((i, s, str(t)) for i, s, t in sorted(splitlines(s), key=key))

    return list(zip(sorted_recs, sorted_recs))
```

**Demo**

```
pairwise_records(records)
```

Output

```
[(('AWS-1', 'opened', '2010-01-23 10:30:08'),
  ('AWS-1', 'closed', '2010-01-23 21:32:50')),
 (('AWS-1', 'opened', '2010-02-01 00:50:28'),
  ('AWS-1', 'closed', '2010-02-27 21:32:50')),
 (('AWS-2', 'opened', '2010-01-23 11:03:56'),
  ('AWS-2', 'closed', '2010-01-23 13:18:32'))]
```

---

**Details**

Kudos to the OP on getting a partial answer with an elaborate regex.  It turns out you can do this more explicitly with more clear regex and without `groupby`.

`splitlines`

We attempt to parse the input string into tuples.  We do this with `re.split` which leaves behind extra elements we don't need.  These extras are cleaned up with `filter` and by unpacking into `(id_, status, time)` where `time` is parsed as a `datetime` object.  The results are tuples of parsed lines.  Example:

```
splitlines("AWS-1 - opened at Jan 23 2010 10:30:08AM")
# (('AWS-1', 'opened', datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 23, 10, 30, 8)),)
```

`pairwise_records`

We sort the tuples by id and `datetime`.  Sorting by time will naturally align pairs in order.  Example, if something *opens* at 9 AM, it must *close* at some future time; time is naturally sorted. Finally, we use a "trick" with iterators to pair the results together.